# Chimney Crown repair vs resealing

Tags: repair, cement, chimney

When is a chimney crown too far gone to repair? In my homebuyer inspection I was told "The cement crown on chimney chase and brick mortar is cracked and/or missing, this needs prep and recoat"

Compared to guides seed online, there seems to be a range of opinions of what's considered acceptable for chimney crown construction. The one on my house seems to be on the minimal side.
My 2 questions are:
Do chimney crowns differ across climates? I live in an area that receives 9" of precip annually. Most snow that falls is gone by 1 or 2 pm.
Is this crown deteriorated to a point where resealing using a bushable sealant is a waste of time?

Photos of the crown
https://imgur.com/a/8JiKj4j

Thank you for taking the time to read my post.

Comment: use a spatula or screwdriver to see if the cracked part comes loose

Comment: A homebuyers report has to include everything the inspector finds.  It doesnt mean you have to action them. Based on what I see in New Zealand, I  would have expected a grade next to it, such as Urgent, Longterm, Maintenance etc.